# Geofencing don't send a notification (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-location

I'm trying to send a notification every time the user passes a store of my client (about 1700 stores) but it's not working.

Can someone tell me why?

My code:

**Store.m**

```
-(CLCircularRegion*)createCircularRegion
{
    CLCircularRegion *region=[[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:self.geoPoint radius:1000 identifier:self.identifier];

    region.notifyOnEntry=YES;

    return region;
}
```

**viewController.m**

```
-(void)startMonitoringAllStores
{
    if (![CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLCircularRegion class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Monitoring is not available for CLCircularRegion class");
    }

    for (Store *currentStore in self.allStores) {
        CLCircularRegion *region=[currentStore createCircularRegion];
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
    }
}

-(void)getStoresFromParse
{
    [self findObjectsWithClassName:@"Stores"];

    [self.allStores addObjectsFromArray:self.allStores];

    [self startMonitoringAllStores];
}
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.locationManager.delegate=self;
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

    return YES;
}


-(void)handleRegionEvent:(CLRegion*)region
{
    NSLog(@"Geofence triggered");
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLCircularRegion class]]) {
        [self handleRegionEvent:region];
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the code related to notification ?

Comment: @Mr.T Oh, forgot it. Updated the post, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can only monitor 20 locations simultaneously in iOS.  See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion:).  Also, make sure you are requesting permission via `requestAlwaysAuthorization`.

One way to get around this limit is to locate the 19 stores closest to the user and monitor those regions, then use the 20th region as an outer boundary around the user's current position whose radius is the distance to the 19th store.  When the user crosses the outer boundary, recompute the nearest 19 stores and the boundary, and repeat.  In code, you would do something like this.  (Note that I have not tested this code; it is just an example.)

```
- (void)installClosestGeofencesTo:(CLLocation *)currentLocation {
    [self removeAllGeofences];
    NSArray *closestStores = [self findClosestStoresTo:currentLocation limit:19];
    for (Store *store in closestStores) {
        CLCircularRegion *region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:store.location radius:100 identifier:store.identifier];
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
    }
    Store *furthestStore = [closestStores lastObject];
    CLCircularRegion *boundaryRegion = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:currentLocation.coordinate radius:furthestStore.distance identifier:@"boundary"];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:boundaryRegion];
}

- (void)removeAllGeofences {
    NSArray *monitoredRegions = [self.locationManager monitoredRegions];
    for (CLRegion *region in monitoredRegions) {
        [self.locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
    }
}

- (NSArray *)findStoresClosestTo:(CLLocation *)location limit:(NSUInteger)limit {
    ...
}
```

In your `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, you would do something like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if ([region.identifier isEqual:@"boundary"]) {
        [self installClosestGeofencesTo:self.locationManager.location];
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do that? Can you please give me an example of code? Thanks!

Comment: Just put some code up there.  Not sure how complete it is, but hopefully that gives you a general idea of what I mean.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that, but I don't think it's the problem here, it's not notify even when I enter the first/last store area. Do you see any other thing that can lead to that?